# ADF: copy distinct values into lookup table, add FK column to dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

Tough to come up with a reasonable title for this one!

I am copying data from a source table (let's call it Books) that has an enum column (Category):

```
ID   Title      Category
----------------------------
1    Test1      Education
2    Blah       Leisure
3    Brown fox  Leisure
...
```

So in this example, there are two enum members, Education and Leisure.

The sink is SQL, and I'm getting the distinct set of enum values and putting them in a lookup table (Categories in this example). The Books table in the sink should have a foreign key column called CategoryId that refers to the PK in the Categories lookup table.

So I need to figure out how to use the text from the Category column to get the ID from the lookup table and use it as the value in the Books.CategoryId column. Anyone know how to do that? I'm just getting my feet wet with ADF so I'll really appreciate any assistance.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a data flow to your pipeline and that will allow you to build a pattern to dedupe and value lookups. If you need some guidance on building data flows, use our YouTube channel of helper videos: https://aka.ms/dataflowvids